# How do I modify this query in elasticsearch (NEST 2.0). to hit a nested object

Tags: c#-4.0, elasticsearch, nest

Here is my query to get the firstname/lastname......

```
    public IEnumerable<ConnectionsModel> NewSearch(SearchQueryModel searchQuery)
    {
        var node = new Uri(Utilities.UrlConstants.SearchServiceUrl);
        var setting = new ConnectionSettings(node);
        var client = new ElasticClient(setting);

        var results = client.Search<Persondb>(s => s
            .From(0)
            .Size(10)
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(b => b
                    .Must(ms =>
                        ms.Match(mt0 => mt0.Field(f => f.FirstName).Query(searchQuery.FirstName)) &&
                        ms.Match(mt0 => mt0.Field(f => f.LastName).Query(searchQuery.LastName)) &&
                        ms.Match(mt0 => mt0.Field(f => f.CurrentCompany).Query(searchQuery.CurrentCompany)) &&
                        ms.Match(mt0 => mt0.Field(f => f.ProfileTitle).Query(searchQuery.ProfileTitle)) &&
                        ms.Match(mt0 => mt0.Field(f => f.IsNewUser).Query("false")) &&

                    ))));
        var queryList = results.Documents.ToList();
```

and here is a sample data with 2 nested objects. references/experiences

```
  {
    "_index": "persondb",
    "_type": "userdata",
    "_id": "5501eb7854355e3b8c879410",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
      "id": "5501eb7854355e3b8c879410",
      "firstName": "Zada",
      "lastName": "Teeters",
      "currentCompany": "John Barns Inc",
      "profileTitle": "software developer",
      "currentlyLooking": true,
      "isNewUser": false,
      "references": [
        {
          "relatedTo": "5540fb080e32651300b02595",
          "relationshipType": "colleage",
          "id": "5540fbac0e32651300b0300d"
        },
        {
          "relatedTo": "554100880e32651300b035d7",
          "relationshipType": "family",
          "id": "554100e90e32651300b03b30"
        }
      ],
      "experiences": [
        {
          "addrCity": "Stockton",
          "addrCountry": "United States",
          "addrState": "California",
          "employer": "KPMG",
          "id": "5501eb7a54355e3b8c8795c3",
          "workType": "Internship",
          "startDate": "2007-09-12T12:39:38.091",
          "endDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
        {
          "addrCity": "Stockton",
          "addrCountry": "United States",
          "addrState": "California",
          "employer": "OSIsoft",
          "id": "5501eb7a54355e3b8c879619",
          "workType": "Internship",
          "startDate": "2007-09-12T12:39:38.386",
          "endDate": "0001-01-01T00:00:00"
        },
```

I need to modify the query to match on references="colleage" and for  experiences am getting a list employers that should match. 
Thanks your help.

This is what I have so far but its not working right.
am submiting a list of employers and its hiting the first employer in the list and ignoring the other items.

```
    var results = client.Search<Persondb>(s => s
    .From(0)
    .Size(100)
    .Query(q => q
        .Bool(b => b
            .Must(ms =>
                ms.Match(mt0 => mt0.Field(f => f.FirstName).Query(searchQuery.FirstName)) &&
                ms.Match(mt0 => mt0.Field(f => f.LastName).Query(searchQuery.LastName)) &&
                ms.Match(mt0 => mt0.Field(f => f.IsNewUser).Query("false")) &&
                ms.Match(mt0 => mt0.Field(f => f.MemberRole).Query("Ordinary")) &&
                q.Nested(n => n
                    .Path(p => p.Reference)
                    .Query(qq => qq.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Reference.First().Relationshiptype).Query(searchQuery.Type)))) &&
                q.Nested(n => n
                    .Path(p => p.Experience)
                    .Query(qq => qq.Match(m => m.Field(f => f.Experience.First().Exployer).Query(searchQuery.company))))
            ))));
queryList = results.Documents.ToList();
```

thanks

```
{
public class Persondb
{
    [String(Store = true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Nest.String(Store = true, Index = Nest.FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Analyzer = "rockon", TermVector = Nest.TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Nest.String(Store = true, Index = Nest.FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, Analyzer = "rockon", TermVector = Nest.TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Nest.String(Store = true, Index = Nest.FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, TermVector = Nest.TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets)]
    public string CurrentCompany { get; set; }

    [Nest.String(Store = true, Index = Nest.FieldIndexOption.Analyzed, TermVector = Nest.TermVectorOption.WithPositionsOffsets)]
    public string ProfileTitle { get; set; }

    [Boolean(Store = true)]
    public bool IsNewUser { get; set; }

    [String(Store = true)]
    public string MemberRole { get; set; }

    [String(Store = true)]
    public string ProfileUrl { get; set; }
    [String(Store = true)]
    public string MembershipType { get; set; }

    #region
    [Nested(IncludeInParent = true)]
    public List<ReferenceObj> Reference { get; set; }

    [Nested(IncludeInParent = true)]
    public List<WorkHistoryObj> WorkHistory { get; set; }
}
[Nest.ElasticsearchType]
public class ReferenceObj
{
    [String(Store = true)]
    public string RelatedTo { get; set; }
    [String(Store = true)]
    public string RelationshipType { get; set; }
    [String(Store = true)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

[Nest.ElasticsearchType]
public class WorkHistoryObj
{
    [String]
    public string AddrCity { get; set; }
    [String]
    public string AddrCountry { get; set; }
    [String]
    public string AddrState { get; set; }
    [String]
    public string Employer { get; set; }
    [String]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [String]
    public string WorkType { get; set; }
    [String]
    public string Industry { get; set; }
    [Date]
    public DateTime StartDate { set; get; }
    [Date]
    public DateTime EndDate { set; get; }
}
```

}

thanks

```
        public IEnumerable<UserData> NewSearch(string memberSoid, MemberSearchQueryModel searchQuery)
    {
        var node = new Uri(Utilities.UrlConstants.SearchServiceUrl);
        var setting = new ConnectionSettings(node);
        var client = new ElasticClient(setting);

        List<UserData> queryList;
        var searchResponse = client.Search<Persondb>(s =>
            s.Query(q => q
                .Nested(n => n
                    .Path(p => p
                        .WorkHistory).Query(qq => qq
                            .Match(m => m.Field(f => f
                                .WorkHistory.FindAll(u => u
                                    .Employer.Contains("GOOGLE INC, MICROSOFT, JOHN INC, TEAM JOBS, SALES FORCE"))))))));
        queryList = searchResponse.Documents.ToList();

        return queryList;
    }
```

I also tried this but it didnt work.
thanks.

Comment: Just added what I have so far. thanks.

Comment: Can you also provide the `Persondb` class definition?

Comment: I have added it.- thanks.